# Webpack 5 publicPath

Tags: fonts, bundler, next.js13, webpack-5, npm-package

I have an npm package of reusable react components built on top of MUI.

I am using webpack 5 as bundler.

Below is part of my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  mode: "production",
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index.js",
    library: "MY_PACKAGE_NAME",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    publicPath: "./",
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    globalObject: "this"
  },
  target: "web",
  
  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "[name][ext]",
          outputPath: "./",
          emit: true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  
  }
}
```

Whenever I use my package in any other repo, I get 404s in the console as the package try to fetch the font files from /

I am not sure what to set my publicPath to ? & should it be dynamic based on the consumer repo deploy ?